# Derivation of data from the object JSON

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

My model

```
public class Gamer
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int MaxScore { get; set; }
public DateTime GamerDate { get; set; }

public int? GameId { get; set; }
public Game Game { get; set; }
}
public class Game
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Gamer> Gamers { get; set; }
public Game()
{
    Gamers = new List<Gamer>();
}
}
```

The response from the server comes in this format:

```
[
{
"Gamers": [],
"Id": 1,
"Name": "World of Tanks"
},
{
"Gamers": [
{
"Id": 2,
"Name": "Meredith",
"MaxScore": 1345,
"GamerDate": "2002-09-01T00:00:00",
"GameId": 2
}
],
"Id": 2,
"Name": "Counter Strike"
 },
{
"Gamers": [
{
"Id": 1,
"Name": "Carson",
"MaxScore": 2345,
"GamerDate": "2005-09-01T00:00:00",
"GameId": 3
},
{
"Id": 3,
"Name": "Arturo",
"MaxScore": 3454,
"GamerDate": "2003-09-01T00:00:00",
"GameId": 3
},
{
"Id": 4,
"Name": "Gytis",
"MaxScore": 1000,
"GamerDate": "2002-09-01T00:00:00",
"GameId": 3
}
],
"Id": 3,
"Name": "Super Mario"
}
]

<body data-ng-controller="AppController">
<h2 style="text-align:center">LeaderBoard</h2>
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-hover"             <style="width:500px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
<tr>
    <th ng-show="onId">#</th>
    <td>Name</td>
    <th>MaxScore</th>
    <th>GamerDate</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="gamer in gamers">
    <td ng-show="onId">{{ gamer.Id }}</td>
    <td>{{ gamer.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ gamer.MaxScore }}</td>
    <td>{{ gamer.GamerDate }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

How to display in the table data on the gamer depending on the game? How to display in the table data on the gamer depending on the game? Must be sorted by day and week.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGeL5.jpg)

Comment: please post your controller or make it as a fiddle and explain clearly about your issue

Comment: I will try to explain by a picture and add image in description question

Comment: The controller submits all the data and caches it on the client for binding.